# How much variability is there in a solar panel?

Tags: solar-cell

If I have two solar panels with identical specifications and they are working under the same condition, how much difference in power output would usually be observed?

Comment: What are your manufacturing tolerances?

Comment: Usually the panels have a power output, including tolerance, that is specified and guaranteed by the manufacturer. I suggest you research a few of those to see how much variation they expect. I am pretty sure power output is tested on 100 percent of units before they leave the factory.

Comment: Yeah with many electronic parts to deal with manufacturing inconsistencies parts are made in bulk and then undergo a "binning" process where they are all tested and separated into batches by quality or operating characteristics.  This helps reduce variation for each product level given more varied manufacturing methods.

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you?

Comment: @KH, yeah I think I have seen some manufacturers offer panels in several different power levels, closely spaced. Like 300, 305, 310 Watts. I am guessing those are binned.